# How to refresh a page only once in a day (after loading the page) on a button click and print the time of last refresh using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, refresh, page-refresh

I have a code that will refresh the page on button click , but when i give only to refresh once in a day , it's not allowing me to refresh . and sometimes when i load the page it will not allow me to refresh the page .

```js
function CheckRefresh(){
  var lastRefresh = new Date(); 
  setInterval(function(){
       var now = new Date();
       if (new Date() - lastRefresh > 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) { 
                  location.reload();
       }

   },60000);
                                           //Console.log(lastrefresh);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" onClick="CheckRefresh()" data-placement="bottom" class="btn-shadow mr-3 btn btn-dark">Refresh</button>
```

I had already referred post related to this on StackOverflow .

Comment: You need some kind of persistent storage to do this. You can do it using a cookie - 
if no cookie is set OR refreshtime in cookie > 24h: allow the refresh

Answer (score 0):

This *should* work, although I could not test it as you are not allowed to set a cookie on a third-party website.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="refresh" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" class="btn-shadow mr-3 btn btn-dark">Refresh</button>

  <script>
    const setRefreshCookie = () => {
      const now = new Date();
      const tomorrow = new Date();
      /*
       * if you want the cookie to expire after 24 hours from the last click
       * on the refresh button, you use only 'tomorrow.setTime()' otherwise,
       * if you want the cookie to expire as soon as the date changes (even if
       * 24 hours have not passed yet) you use both 'tomorrow.setTime()' and
       * 'tomorrow.setHours()'
       */
      tomorrow.setTime(now.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
      tomorrow.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

      document.cookie = 'preventRefesh=true;expires=' + tomorrow.toUTCString() + 'domain=yourdomain.tld;path=/path/to/page';
    };

    const checkRefreshCookie = () => {
      return document.cookie.split('; ').some(cookie => cookie.split('=')[0] === 'preventRefesh');
    };
    
    const refreshBtn = document.getElementById('refresh');
    const isRefreshCookieSet = checkRefreshCookie();

    document.addEventListener('load', () => {
      if (isRefreshCookieSet ) {
        /*
         * disable the button, so that the user has a visual feedback
         */
        refreshBtn.setAttribute('disabled', true);
      }
    });

    refreshBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      if (!isRefreshCookieSet ) {
        setRefreshCookie();
        // location.reload();
        console.log('refeshing the page...');
      }
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yeah it works fine , but when i refresh my browser refresh button everything start's from first  that is refresh button will be enabled again ,  is there any solution for that . it would be a great help .

Comment: i want in such a way that whatever if someone refresh using button then the button should be disabled throughout the day even if we refresh the browser or reloads the page

Comment: @sreeshasudhev You cannot prevent a native refresh event.

Comment: @sreeshasudhev, you can move the logic to disable the page button from the button click event to the document load event (I updated the snippet in order to do so) but you cannot - and you should not -prevent the user from refreshing the page using the browser toolbar button.

Comment: but if it is deployed in the server and many user loads the webpage . refresh button will be enabled na

Comment: Well, that is how client-side code works... If what you want is that when someone clicks on the button, the button is disabled for him/her _and for everybody else_, you will have to save the time of the last click somewhere on the server, fetch that info when the page loads and use it to enable/disable the button. But that is not something you can achieve with React (alone).

Comment: Okay got it . Thanks